# Responsive Web Design in CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am fairly new to using CSS and as such have been working to better understand responsive web design in order to implement it on a site that I plan to use as a portfolio project. I am currently trying to resize a set of three unordered lists and a set of 6 images when at three different screen sizes in pixels. When I open the project in dev mode and attempt to use responsive, nothing on the page changes as it sticks to the large size of three per row for each item. After looking at my code it doesn't seem like anything I have done is incorrect and I could use some help reviewing it.

In my CSS file, .ProjectImageGrid refers to the grid used to order the images based on size of device, .AboutMeGrid is the grid for my three unordered lists, .ProjectImage and .AboutMeLists are for formatting for the two respectively. In case you would like to view the HTML code for this part, I will also list that below, but I do not think the issue is within that code.

```css
.container { /* Sets page margins and max size */
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.AboutMeGrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .AboutMeGrid {
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
  .AboutMeGrid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  }
}

.ProjectImageGrid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
    .ProjectImageGrid {
        grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
    .ProjectImageGrid {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    }
}

.ProjectImage {
    justify-self: center;
    padding: 4%;
}

.AboutMeLists {
    list-style: none;
    font-style: italic;
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My First Site</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="Intro">
                <img src="Assets/gvbhnj.jpg" width="150" height="150"/>
                <h1 id="MyName">Name Here</h1>
                <h3>Simple Bio</h3>
                <p>You miss 100% of the shots you don't take</p>
            </div>

            <div class="AboutMeGrid">
                <div class="IAm">
                    <h1>I am</h1>
                    <ul class="AboutMeLists">
                        <li>Hard working</li>
                        <li>A team player</li>
                        <li>Willing to try new things</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="Hobbies">
                    <h1>I like to</h1>
                    <ul class="AboutMeLists">
                        <li>Play Baseball</li>
                        <li>Play videogames</li>
                        <li>Practice coding</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="LinkSet">
                    <h1>My Links</h1>
                    <ul class="AboutMeLists">
                        <li>
                            <a href="https://GitHub.com/SampleLink">GitHub</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="https://LinkedIn.com/in/SampleLink">LinkedIn</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/SampleLink/">Facebook</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div>
                <h1>My Projects</h1>
                <div class="ProjectImageGrid">
                    <img class="ProjectImage" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300"/>
                    <img class="ProjectImage" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300"/>
                    <img class="ProjectImage" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300"/>
                    <img class="ProjectImage" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300"/>
                    <img class="ProjectImage" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300"/>
                    <img class="ProjectImage" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300"/>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `flexbox` on your container is a very responsive and mobile-friendly way to display your content. I added a `container` to your HTML and gave it a flex display. Also, I added `justify-content: center;` so that everything remains in the center when resizing. See the changes I made below.

```css
.container { /* Sets page margins and max size */
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.AboutMeGrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .AboutMeGrid {
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
  .AboutMeGrid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  }
}

.ProjectImageGrid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
    .ProjectImageGrid {
        grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
    .ProjectImageGrid {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    }
}

.ProjectImage {
    justify-self: center;
    padding: 4%;
}

.AboutMeLists {
    list-style: none;
    font-style: italic;
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="AboutMeGrid">
    <div class="IAm">
        <h1>I am</h1>
        <ul class="AboutMeLists">
            <li>Hard working</li>
            <li>A team player</li>
            <li>Willing to try new things</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="Hobbies">
        <h1>I like to</h1>
        <ul class="AboutMeLists">
            <li>Play Baseball</li>
            <li>Play videogames</li>
            <li>Practice coding</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="LinkSet">
        <h1>My Links</h1>
        <ul class="AboutMeLists">
            <li>
                <a href="https://GitHub.com/SampleLink">GitHub</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="https://LinkedIn.com/in/SampleLink">LinkedIn</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/SampleLink/">Facebook</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <h1>My Projects</h1>
    <div class="ProjectImageGrid">
        <img class="ProjectImage" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300"/>
        <img class="ProjectImage" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300"/>
        <img class="ProjectImage" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300"/>
        <img class="ProjectImage" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300"/>
        <img class="ProjectImage" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300"/>
        <img class="ProjectImage" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300"/>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the suggestion. I tried to add the lines you suggested in order to fix my issue. But it still seems to not work for some reason. Based off the other response I got though I realized I didn't add the head to what I submitted for the question which contains code relevant to this so I am uploading this in order to help make my code easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You might not be setting your viewport in your html

If you haven't include this line within the head of your html

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

You pretty much need to include this line whenever you ware doing responsive design as it gives the browser more instructions to help with determining when to be responsive.

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion. I did include the viewport in my head, I just didn't show the head so that is my fault. I'll edit to show the full thing. I copy pasted your viewport just to double check though and it is still having issues.